# PDO connection AWS RDS charset

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-web-services, database-connection, amazon-rds

when trying to connect to an AWS RDS database through PDO I get

```
"Erreur : SQLSTATE[HY000] [2054] Server sent charset unknown to the client"
```

I've read somewhere that I could try to change my.cnf file. 
I didn't find one so created it in **Applications/MAMP/conf** and put

```
[client]
default-character-set=utf8

[mysql]
default-character-set=utf8


[mysqld]
collation-server = utf8_unicode_ci
init-connect='SET NAMES utf8'
character-set-server = utf8
```

but it still doesn't work... (I'm working on a Mac with MAPMP and php 7.0.15)
Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

The character set should be -

PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"

here is sample PDO connect code -

```
$host = "asjhdkjashdkj.asjdhaskd.ap-southeast-1.rds.amazonaws.com";
$username = "user";
$password = "pass";
$db_name = "database";
return new PDO('mysql:host=' . $host . ';dbname=' . $db_name, $username, $password, array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION, PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
```